# What dose Ethereum protocol version mean?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

Running following command I get the response as follows:
Command:
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_protocolVersion","params":[],"id":67}' 3.32.29.150:8545
Response:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":"0x3f"}

As per the response the protocol version is "0x3f", my question where it is defined inside the go-ethereum  code?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum is a protocol that is based on the [The RLPx Transport Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) protocol. Every time we have a change in the Ethereum protocol, we have to update the protocol version. For more info about all the protocol versions in Ethereum please refer to this official protocol change log:

https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/caps/eth.md#change-log